# What's the deal with this tattoo?

Tags: грамматика, перевод

I saw the following picture: [Link](https://townsquare.media/site/366/files/2022/06/attachment-hellfest_wk01_0355.jpg)

As I see it, the text in the tattoo says:

> в воду нечего бояться дождя

This seems odd to me. "Бояться дождя" definitely means "to be afraid of rain," but on the other hand, "нечего бояться" means 'there's nothing to be afraid of"! The combination of those two elements doesn't seem right. Also, "в воду" means "into water." Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have to close this question - it's not about Russian language but rather about an interpretation of some vague tattoo inscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely, there's one more word higher up at shoulder level. Most likely, the complete phrase is "*Упавшему в воду нечего бояться дождя.*", literally "he who fell in water doesn't have to be afraid of the rain".